# transition of images with javascript as a video

Tags: javascript

as the effect of bottom of this page

I tried several ways but have not succeeded

http://larealpari.com/?

```
    function () {
        (function (e) {
   var n, r, i, s, o, u, a, f, l, c, h, p, d, v, m;
                return e.gc.active = !0, s = parseInt(t.delay), n = parseInt(t.count), v = parseInt(t.width), h = 0, l = 0, c = 0, u = parseInt(t.height), p = s, o = !0, window.timeout = null, window.interval = null, a = 0, m = 0, d = function () {
                    var t, r, i;
                    return i = e(window).width() / e(window).height(), r = v / u, i > r ? (h = e(window).width(), t = Math.ceil(u * (h / v)), c = parseInt((t - e(window).height()) / 2), l = 0) : (t = e(window).height(), h = Math.ceil(v * (t / u)), l = parseInt((h - e(window).width()) / 2), c = 0), e("#frame").css({
                        "background-size": "" + h * n + "px " + t + "px",
                        "background-position": "-" + (a * h + l) + "px -" + c + "px"
                    })
        })(jQuery
    );
```

Comment: Those variable names are impossible to read.

Comment: this is the code of the page you put as an example so I do not quite understand how it works